# ActiveRecord и словарь из СУБД

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlalchemy, django-orm

Вопрос такой. Вот к примеру, при пректировании СУБД есть методика создания словарей, то есть отдельной таблицы, которая содержит коды и/или имена. Эту таблицу подключат по вторичному ключу к основной таблице, к полу в котором требуется перечисление по словарю.

Теперь такой вопрос, если ли где-нибудь в питоновских ActiveRecord ORM (Django Models, SQLAlchemy) возможность работать с такими словарями?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации SQLAlchemy описаны самые различные варианты создания таких ассоциаций http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#proxying-to-dictionary-based-collections